# VS Code does not override default function argument suggestions when using quotes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense suggested arguments do not get overwritten when using single or double quotes

Observed behavior:

[image: Intellisense Suggestion]

[image: Using quotes does enqoute the string]

Expected behavior:

[image]

[image]

Worth noting that I do get the expected behavior by any other character or by hitting the space bar; e.g., hitting "a" when the highlighted suggestion "filepath_or_buffer" is shown produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I seem to have found the solution just after having sent this post: Obviously, the setting "Editor: Auto Surround" is the culprit. Setting it to "never" does the trick for me.